# Mutate type of generic variable in Rust

Tags: variables, generics, types, rust

I know that you can't mutate the type of a variable.
So coming from other programming languages where following would work:

```rust
struct Point<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Point { x: 1, y: 1 }; // p is type of Point<u8> now
    p = Point { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 }; // p should be type of Point<float> now
}
```

My use case for this would, that you assign a default value to variable and i specific case you change the value. But both are e.g. of the generic type `Point<T>` and the rest of the code just works with this generic type and not a specific one.

What is the best practice in Rust to achieve this kind of workflow?

*EDIT:*

A better example to understand what i want to accomplish is maybe following: 
`DateTime<Tz>` is given by the crate `chrono`.

```rust
fn main() {
   let is_utc = ....;

   let mut datetime = Local::now(); // datetime is now of type DateType<Local>

   if is_utc {
       datetime = Utc::now(); // datetime is now of type DateType<Utc>
   }

   format(datetime);
}


fn format<Tz: TimeZone>(datetime: DateTime<Tz>) where Tz::Offset : fmt::Display {
    // here is someother code to justify this extra function :)
    datetime.format("%a %b %e %k:%M:%S %Z %Y");
}
```

So the function `format` does not are what `Tz` is except it should be of type `TimeZone`.

Comment: As you said: You can't change the type. Also I don't see why you would need that from your comment. You need beforehand to know which type you expect (you can't change the type of values inside a `Vec` at runtime as well, can you?). I see two possibilities. Use [`Default::default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) and add the requirement `T: Default` and then you can write: `let mut p: Point<f32> = Point::Default`

Comment: You could do this in a weakly typed language, but in strongly typed languages which support generics, you cannot change the generic parameter. E.g. if you write `Point<int> p = new Point<int>(1, 2);`  in C#, you cannot write `p = new Point<float>(1f, 2f);` afterwards. If the class was mutable, you couldn't even write `p.X = 2.1f;` because `p` is a struct containing integers. Think of generic classes as templates for concrete classes that are set in stone when you specify a parameter.

Comment: @hellow this not exactly what i want to do. See my edited question.

Comment: @Groo yes i understand that. I just want to know a best practice code how to approach my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your multi variable type in `enum`,

```rust
enum Num {
    int(i32),
    float(f64)
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Point { x: Num::int(1), y: Num::int(1) };
    p = Point { x: Num::float(1.0), y: Num::float(1.0) };
}
```